# chrome extension download files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm writing a js extension for chrome that should download multiple created files. 
the problem is that chrome auto opens the file in the current tab at the following address:
filesystem:https://stackoverflow.com//temporary/myfile.ini
and second if I cycle on an array made this way
fileini = [ ["filename",file-content], [], ... ] it just print the last one
and if I try to cycle on it using a setTimeout I get an error from the console

below I post the code

function createDataFile(filename, content) {

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024 * 20, function(fs) {

    fs.root.getFile(filename, {
        create : true
    }, function(fileEntry) {

        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

            var blob = new Blob(content);
            console.log("5");
            fileWriter.addEventListener("writeend", function() {
                // navigate to file, will download

                location.href = fileEntry.toURL();
            }, false);

            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, function() {
        });
    }, function() {
    });
}, errorHandler);
```

}

function errorHandler(e) {
    var msg = '';

```
switch (e.code) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
        msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
        break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
        msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
        break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
        msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
        break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
        msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
        break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
        msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
        break;
    default:
        msg = 'Unknown Error';
        break;
};

console.log('Error: ' + msg);
```

}

createFileCycle();

```
function prnt(x) {
    var y;
    if (fileini[x] !== undefined) {
        createDataFile(fileini[x][0], objToArray(fileini[x][1]));
        y = x - 1;
        console.log("printed file" + x);
    } else {
        y = x - 1;
    }
    if (x > 0)
        return setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("going to print file " + y);
            prnt(y);
        }, 500);
    else
        return 0;
}

prnt(fileini.length - 1);
```

}

function createFileCycle() creates fileini array as explained above

I hope someone could help me.
btw months ago on an old notebook running ubuntu 32bit I had it working, now on windows 7 it doesn't work and I cannot get around the problem.